# Installing Mongo Driver on MAMP

Tags: php, module, installation, mamp

I have downloaded, compiled and installed the latest mongo driver for php & it's been placed at:

```
 /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so
```

How would I go about adding this to the MAMP php.ini file? I have looked at just trying to add the "extention=mongo.so" however this does not work. I also tried to place the mongo.so file inside the dir:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-xxx/
```

And added the correct line of code to php.ini...

Would I have to tell it the directory the extension is in?

Answer (score 7):

To install latest Mongo driver on MAMP

1 - install **autoconf** using homebrew or Mac Ports

> brew install autoconf

2 - Download php 5.4.10 source from [php.net](https://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.10.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror).

3 - rename uncompressed php source folder from **php-5.4.10** to **php** and paste it in this folder

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/

4- using the terminal open php folder and run ./configure

> cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/ && **./configure**

5 - Add MAMP bin to your ~/.bash_profile

> echo "export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
> source ~/.bash_profile

6 - install latest mongo

> pecl install mongo

7- restart MAMP server :).

8- Enable the extension Edit /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini Add the following line after the section named "; Extensions":

> extension=mongo.so

Comment: Great, thank you! But there is one more step:

8- Enable the extension
Edit `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini`

Add the following line after the section named "; Extensions":

`extension=mongo.so`

Answer (score 1):

Before you go off trying to install mongo, you really should install MAMPs special tools for adding extensions and follow this tutorial for getting set up:

http://blog.jellystyle.com/post/37099202581/installing-php-extensions-with-mamp

This allows you to use the correct pecl, the correct pear, and will install `mongo.so` in the correct location for MAMP to use it.

Then, from there just run `sudo pecl install mongo` and restart the MAMP service.

Then.... edit the php.ini file:

1. Find the `Extensions` section via search (in vim you can just type `/Extensions` and hit enter
2. under the `Extensions` section add this line if it isn't already there: `extension=mongo.so`
3. make sure the path to `mongo.so` is something like this: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mongo.so

Answer (score 0):

Write a short PHP script which contains the line `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Run it. Search for `extension_dir` to figure out the directory where extensions are supposed to be loaded from.

If you want to use PHP CLI, run `php -i | grep extension_dir` as well. Both should point to the same directory. Place your `mongo.so` there.

Next, have a look at `Loaded Configuration File`. This is the `php.ini` used for Apache or CLI (these files usually are different). Add `extension=mongo.so` in the proper one (or in both).

Restart Apache (done via `sudo service apache2 restart` on Unix) and check `phpinfo()` output again. MongoDB should show up as loaded extension.

Comment: I have managed to ge phpinfo() to say this "extension_dir: /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626" i have the mongo.so in both the php extension dir & the MAMP php dir yet i am not getting any results.

Comment: @CallumBonnyman You still need to load the extension. In `php.ini` you have to add `extension=mongo.so` to load it. `phpinfo()` then will show MongoDB extension as available extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the problems i was having was trying to use MAMP which was confusing me. After much failure I just decided to use PHP as it is and it worked correctly. There was a good guide to any setup instructions here: http://www.phpied.com/installing-php-and-apache-on-mac-osx-that-was-pretty-easy/